# Apply user defined function to DataFrame fails, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have below dataframe, want to separate date and text from the field "Indicator_NameB" and I have written function "String_Year_Pick_V2"

Data:

```
    Indicator_NameB
       2011-12 (RE)
       2012-13 (BE)
        2007-08
    Approved Outlay
Total for 11th Plan

Data['Indicator_NameB'].map(str).apply(String_Year_Pick_V2)
```

`KN.String_Year_Pick_V2` - This function separates Text and Date from Each value of "Indicator_NameB" and returns as series value like `(RE), 2011-12`

Getting below error:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'get_indexer'
```

Then I update to Dataframe:

```
DataT[['Indicator_NameB', 'Year']] = DataT['Indicator_NameB'].map(str).apply(String_Year_Pick_V2)
```

I suspect,

```
String_Year_Pick_V2('2007-08') gives '', '2007-08'
String_Year_Pick_V2('Approved Outlay') gives 'Approved Outlay', ''
```

may be above results causing the error

Comment: does axis=1 work? `DataT['Indicator_NameB'].map(str).apply(String_Year_Pick_V2,axis=1)` hard to say since we dont know how the function treats striings as `2012-13 (BE)`

Comment: @anky_91, Error: TypeError: String_Year_Pick_V2() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: can you also post the function: `String_Year_Pick_V2`

Comment: @anky_91, Sorry My mistake, there was some return statement in String_Year_Pick_V2 which returns Series values and some variables, I have corrected it as pd.Series([String, Year]), Now works fine. Thanks a lot for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**String_Year_Pick_V2** - Function has multiple return statements, I suppose to return series values and some code returns "String", "Year" as variables, this caused the error.